# call function with className.onclick JS

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, inline

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("elements"); // this element contains more than 1 DOMs.
el.onclick = function() { console.log("target name should be here")};
```

So I don't want to have inline JS, I want to fire function when it click to a specific DOM that has same class to any other elements.
Could anyone help please?

Comment: that method returns an array of elements... even if there is only one element with that classname.

Comment: I just found that jquery could help me with this. Thanks for everybody answers , I've learned something new

Answer (score 9):

You cannot attach an event listener to an array of objects, which is that function will be returning.

**Instead, loop through the list returned and attach the event listener to each item.**

Comment: Technically speaking, the return value of `getElementsByClassName()` is not an array but an object that resembles an array.

Comment: @Mr.X agreed. Thanks for catching it!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `document.getElementsByClassName`, it's better to use `document.querySelectorAll` as it's `getElementsbyClassName` returns you a live HTMLCollection whereas `querySelectorAll` returns you static NodeList.

```
 var el = document.querySelectorAll(".elements"); // this element contains more than 1 DOMs.
    for(var i =0; i < el.length; i++) {
        el[i].onclick = function() { console.log("target name should be here")};
    }
```

In case you wan to track the element count inside your event handler, then its better to wrap the event handler inside IIFE

```
 var el = document.querySelectorAll(".elements"); // this element contains more than 1 DOMs.
 // as it contains a NodeList, it's desirable to iterate through the list and bind events.                   
  for(var i =0; i < el.length; i++) {
      // Inside the event handler function, if you want to access i, then its better to wrap it inside IIFE
      (function(i) {
            el[i].onclick = function() { console.log("target name should be here")};   
       })(i);
   }
```

Comment: I would still use `document.getElementsByClassName()` because it's [faster](https://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/18)  for ie8 support you could always do `document.getElementsByClassName() || document.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: Actually getElementsByClassName is just as effective as querySelectorAll in modern browsers. The only change in support would be for IE8, and even then there's only a slight advantage to querySelectorAll. Basically instead of "no, this won't work" you can say "well, it might work"

Comment: In terms of performance and support yes. But getElementsbyClassName returns you live node list whereas querySelectorAll returns you static nodelist. So because of that i would avoid looping through a live nodelist.

Comment: @mohamedrias `getElementsbyClassName()` returns an `HTMLCollection` and not a `NodeList`

Comment: Oh ya, I've mentioned it correctly in answer. but referred it wrongly in comment @Mr.X

Comment: Mr.X, Good catch with that! 
@mohamedrias Good call as well. The difference between Live and Static is important so I'm glad you mentioned it! I guess it all comes down to if the web page is dynamic or static, but to avoid issues querySelectorAll() is probably the better way to go if you want to play it safe and cover your bases. That is, if you're not concerned about a little dip in speed.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector returns an array of elements so you need to loop them.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("elements"); 
// loops els
for(var i = 0, x = els.length; i < x; i++) {
    els[i].onclick = function(){
        // do something
        console.log('target name should be here');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("elements"); 
// this element contains more than 1 DOMs.
for(var i=0;i < el.length;i++) {

el[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
console.log("My index number is: " + i)});
}
```

This will loop through the node list returned by the query and return the index number on click into the console. If you need to get a specific element and the page is static(meaning the indexes are going to be the same) you can grab the index number through this process, then change the code so that on load you specify:

```
var el = document.getElementsByClassName("elements"); 
// this element contains more than 1 DOMs.
var i = indexNumber; 
el[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
// do whatever
});
```

where var i is the target index number.

Answer (score 1):

You either loop over all the elements referenced by the `el` variable and attach the event handler on each element as you see fit, or delegate the event handler to `document` for example and fire it accordingly.

Either way you choose, you should note that `onclick` prop and its siblings are not defined on `HTMLCollection` instances or any other array-like objects returned by `querySelectorAll()` etc.

```
//ES6 syntax, registering a click event handler on each element 
[].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('elements')).forEach(ele => ele.onclick = () => console.log('whatever'));

//ES6, Event delegation
document.addEventListener('click', eve => {
  eve.target.classList.contains('elements') ? console.log('whatever') : undefined ; 
});
```