# Why does my javascript redirect not work ""?

Tags: javascript, html

Why doesn't the `redirectFunction()` function redirect to another link?

```js
   document.querySelectorAll(".redirectBtn") .addEventListener("click", redirectFunction);
   function redirectFunction() {
      window.location.href = ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475323/call-function-with-classname-onclick-js/29475365");
   }
```

```html
<h1>Redirect to a Webpage Example</h1>
<button class="redirectBtn">Redirect</button>
<h2>Click the above button to Redirect to another Webpage</h2>
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` returns a collection, not a single element on which you can call `.addEventListener(...)`. You probably meant to use `querySelector(...)`

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.redirectBtn') is retrieving an array of html Nodes. Use document.querySelector('.redirectBtn') instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `querySelectorAll` returns an array of elements that matches the query. Since you only have one element, with that query, you need to use `querySelector`, which only selects one (1st) element.

```js
document.querySelector(".redirectBtn") .addEventListener("click", redirectFunction);
   function redirectFunction() {
      window.location.href = ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475323/call-function-with-classname-onclick-js/29475365");
   }
```

```html
<h1>Redirect to a Webpage Example</h1>
<button class="redirectBtn">Redirect</button>
<h2>Click the above button to Redirect to another Webpage</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`. [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a list of dom elements on which you can't invoke the `addEventListener` method.

```js
   document.querySelector(".redirectBtn") .addEventListener("click", redirectFunction);
   function redirectFunction() {
      window.location.href = ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475323/call-function-with-classname-onclick-js/29475365");
   }
```

```html
<h1>Redirect to a Webpage Example</h1>
<button class="redirectBtn">Redirect</button>
<h2>Click the above button to Redirect to another Webpage</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: `querySelectorAll` always return an array. You cannot add event listener to an array. Loop through the nodes and add event listener on individual node.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".redirectBtn").forEach((node) => node.addEventListener("click", redirectFunction))
function redirectFunction() {
  window.location.href = ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475323/call-function-with-classname-onclick-js/29475365");
}
```

```html
<h1>Redirect to a Webpage Example</h1>
<button class="redirectBtn">Redirect</button>
<h2>Click the above button to Redirect to another Webpage</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a node collection, you have to use a loop to add the `eventListener`s or you can use `querySelector` instead like this

```js
document.querySelector(".redirectBtn").addEventListener("click", redirectFunction);
```

Answer (score -1):

there is a space here:

you have to remove it

```js
document.querySelector(".redirectBtn")XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.addEventListener("click", redirectFunction);
```